# SFTP/SSH/RSYNC to google cloud platform using service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh-keys

Is it possible to connect to google cloud platform VMs using a service account and a standard ssh/sftp client such as putty, filezilla etc.

I believe it's possible to do using the gcloud utility but I need it to work with other clients.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools
 and https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sa_ssh_manual

Comment: It looks like that only specifies using the "gcloud compute ssh" tool, I need to be able to connect using another sftp or ssh client. _In some situations, you might want to connect to instances and run commands as if you were the service account associated with that instance. The gcloud compute ssh command lets you use the SSH credentials of a service account to connect from one instance to another, letting you run commands on the second instance as the service account._